# My ARIMA Prediction seems to be logaritmic. Does it make sense?

Tags: python, forecasting, predict, arima, forecast

I have this df. It is a dataset with a lot of data, in which date and temperatures.:

```
dades_estacio='Dades_estacio_Das.csv'

dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%Y-%m-%d')
df = pd.read_csv(dades_estacio, parse_dates=['DATA'],date_parser=dateparse)
print ('\n Parsed Data:')
df=df.drop('Unnamed: 0',axis=1)
df.head()
```

Next I check for stationarity. p-value=0.001910736198530445, so I assume it is stationary:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
def ad_test(dataset):
     dftest = adfuller(dataset, autolag = 'AIC')
     print("1. ADF : ",dftest[0])
     print("2. P-Value : ", dftest[1])
     print("3. Num Of Lags : ", dftest[2])
     print("4. Num Of Observations Used For ADF Regression:",      dftest[3])
     print("5. Critical Values :")
     for key, val in dftest[4].items():
         print("\t",key, ": ", val)
ad_test(df['Temp mitja'])
```

I apply the ARIMA model, and get the best model is order (2,0,2):

```
#Aplicación Metodo ARIMA
from pmdarima import auto_arima
stepwise_fit = auto_arima(df['Temp mitja'], trace=True,
suppress_warnings=True)
```

I train the model:

```
#Split the dataset
print(df.shape)
train=df.iloc[:-30]
test=df.iloc[-30:]
print(train.shape,test.shape)

from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
model=ARIMA(train['Temp mitja'],order=(2,0,2))
model=model.fit()
model.summary()
```

Now I predict the test with the model:

```
start=len(train)
end=len(train)+len(test)-1
pred=model.predict(start=start,end=end,typ='levels')
test['ARIMA Predictions']=pred

#Representación gráfica:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,6))
ax.plot(test['DATA'], test['Temp mitja'], color = 'tab:orange',label='Temp mitja')
ax.plot(test['DATA'], test['ARIMA Predictions'], color = 'tab:blue',label='ARIMA Predictions')
plt.xlabel('DATA')
plt.ylabel('Temperatura mitja')
ax.legend(loc = 'upper right')
plt.show()
```

But I get the ARIMA Prediction is a curve that seems a logaritm. Is that correct? Or it should seem a line with lots of picks like the test one?